# Migrate .NET Core from 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, startup

I was trying to migrate my .net core web app from 2.2 to 3.1
I've changed the target framework from .csproj file and then installed all necessary dependencies from Nuget Package Manager
And When I Ran the Project I got this Message

**

> 500.37 ANCM Failed to Start Within Startup Time Limit

**

Please I need help.
Important note: I've changed my Startup.cs and made some changes as mentioned in the official website of Microsoft but still the same.

Comment: please post startup.cs changes, are you running the app locally?

Comment: i've seen this error message on IIS webservers - usually when the framework wasn't installed. (meaning: both dotnet core AND asp.net core)

Comment: you need to install or repair https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle if running from IIS

Comment: Yes I will tell you but now I'm getting this error:
Error MSB3021 Unable to copy file "\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App.exe" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App.exe". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App.exe' is denied. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.target

Comment: @viveknuna no I'm not hosting yet, I've tried to publish the project and changed the stdoutlog to true in web.config but it didn't post anyting useful but i tried to make publish

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET CORE 3.1 on Azure Web Sites: 500.37 ANCM Failed to Start Within Startup Time Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847547/net-core-3-1-on-azure-web-sites-500-37-ancm-failed-to-start-within-startup-tim)

Comment: @Stefan I wanna know where to change the startup limit.
but right now I'm stuck with another error message which says access is denied :/

Comment: If you get a new error, that would be a new question, right?

Comment: "Access to the path '...  is denied." Means the executable process is still running. Open your task manager and kill the project process and msbuil.exe still running (or, reboot would do as well, though a bit overkill)

Comment: @Pac0 , yes it was solved thanks

Comment: @Stefan now I'm run into another problem which ts errors
because the project is implemented in angular v4 so do u think this might conflict with the migration?

Comment: I would ask a new question relating to that to attract new attention and experts in that field.

Comment: @Stefan I'm now stuck with 500.37 ANCM Failed to Start Within Startup Time Limit again :/

Comment: @Stefan should I do something in web.config? this is the message from logs: 
021-06-16 05:28:16,644 INFO InsiteApp.Program - Application - Main is invoked

2021-06-16 05:28:17,854 INFO App.Program - host created

Hosting environment: Development

Comment: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

contd: Now listening on: https://localhost:5001

Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Comment: @Stefan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004329/migrating-net-core-2-2-to-net-core-3-1-error-500-37-startup-time-limit

Answer (score 0):

1.close applications running on the system

2.turns out because access takes a long time

3.Webconfig upgrade startupTimeLimit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524792(v=vs.90)

We solved this solution by increasing the startupTimeLimit to 300

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
      <location>
        <system.webServer>
          <aspNetCore xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(startupTimeLimit)" startupTimeLimit="300">
          </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
      </location>
    </configuration>
```